# TimePickerDialog Autamatically sets AM when I pick a time even I selected PM

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

this the code I'm using for timepicker dialog and it automatically sets AM with my time even if I select PM while picking a time

```
 private fun timePicker() {
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
           val timelistener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
               var hr = hourOfDay
               if (hr>12)
                   hr -=12
               cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr)
               cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
               binding.addMoretimeStamp.text = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(cal.time)
           }
            TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), timelistener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show()
        }
```

Comment: `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr)` should be as `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)` . You don't have to calculate Hours u r Already using a date format it will take care of it .

Comment: thanks... issue is resolved